# how to replace the first "9" in a string with another character in postgresql database column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column "pnum" in a "test" table. 
I'd like to replace the leading "9" in pnum with "*" for every record.

```
testdb=# select * from test limit 5;
 id      name       pnum
===========================================
 1       jk         912312345
 2       tt         9912333333
```

I would like the pnums to look like this:

```
 id      name       pnum
===========================================
 1       jk         *12312345
 2       tt         *912333333
```

How would I do something like this in postgres?

EDIT 1:

I have tried something like this so far:

```
select id, name, '*' && substring(pnum FROM 2 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(pnum)-1 )  from test limit 3;
```

Also tried this:

```
select id, name, '*' || substring(pnum FROM 2 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(pnum)-1 )  from test limit 3;
```

Neither one has worked...

EDIT 2:

I figured it out:

```
select id, name, '*'::text || substring(pnum FROM 2 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(pnum)-1 )  from test limit 3;
```

Comment: What is the result for `129111`?

Answer (score 1):

See function regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [, flags text]) [String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT regexp_replace('9912333333', '^[9]', '*');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 *912333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Postgres' string manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) functions for this. In your case "Substring" and "Char_Length"

```
'*' || Substring(<yourfield> FROM 2 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(<yourfield>)-1) as outputfield
```

Comment: thanks.  sorry, i'm such a noob. but can you give me a complete example of how to update the table?  I'm also trying to read the useful link you gave me

Comment: I think i've got the select statement working except the || part is failing

Comment: Perhaps postgres was stressing over that asterisk in the concat... Glad you figured it out!